# Confusion with KCL in Telegrapher's equation's derivation

Tags: transmission-line

In a text about the derivation of Telegrapher's equation the following is given:

[image]

[image]

But what is the last term I pointed with a red arrow in KCL? There is only one current entering and two leaving through C and G. To me the currents in the KCL should be the following marked in red:

[image]

What is *i(z+Δz, t)* in their KCL? It is very counterintuitive. Isn't already *i(z+Δz, t)* is equal to the sum of the current through C and G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That term represents the current that leaves this segment of transmission line and enters the next one to the right.

Remember, this analysis applies to a short segment of transmission line that is part of an infinite sequence of such segments.

Comment: I still dont understand. Could you show it on a simple drawing? There is i(z,t) entering and this divides into two currents through C and G, there is no other branch.. To me the return current must be equal to i(z,t). (?)

Comment: It's shown in the upper right corner of the drawing you already have. Imagine an arrow pointing to the right from there.

Comment: Oh now I got it thanks, that flows to the next segment.